# How can I copy items from one table and insert them in another table ASP.NET CORE EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'd like to take items from one table and insert them in another table. But I get this error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ShuttersInc.Areas.Identity.Data.CreatedProducts>' to 'ShuttersInc.Models.ConfirmedProducts'

I know what the error means, that I must not use a list but I can't come up with another solution since if I don't use a list I still get another error.

```
 string user = User.Identity.Name;
 var itemsToCheckOut = _context.CreatedProducts.Where(u => u.User.Equals(user)).ToList(); 

 _context.ConfirmedProducts.AddRange(itemsToCheckOut);
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

PS: `CreatedProducts` is the table from where I want to copy the items and insert them into `ConfirmedProducts` which is another table.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better that you declare two contexts; the first one is attached with `"CreatedProducts"` and the second one os attached to `"ConfirmedProducts"`.

Next, you must declare something similar to DTO(Data transfer to object), which it will take the first type `"CreatedProducts"` and convert it to the type `"ConfirmedProducts"`, by this way you will also guarantee error management.

I think you must apply seperation of concerns, so each context must keep it's own logic, so that you can deal more properly with objects type.

I hope my answer helps you.

Greetings.